# .htaccess rule match part of new url and use as query string for old url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to match part of a URL and then use the matched expression to append onto the end of a query string from the old URL.

I have the following line in `.htaccess`, once I've worked out what I'm doing wrong I'll be able to fix the rest so for now I will just focus on the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^league/([^/]*)$/matches/? index.php?page_id=1074&league=$1
```

I would like `([^/]*)$` to appear where `$1` is

So essentially: `/league/29/matches/` would point to `index.php?page=1074&league=29`

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^league/([^/]*)$/matches/? index.php?page_id=1074&league=$1
> ```

The `$` (end-of-string anchor) after the subpattern `([^/]*)$`, in the middle of the regex, does not make sense here and will cause the regex to fail. You should also be using the `+` quantifier here (1 or more). You are also missing the end-of-string anchor (`$`) at the end of the regex (otherwise the trailing `/?` is superfluous). Although you shouldn't really make the trailing slash optional on the rewrite as it potentially opens you up for duplicate  content. (You should redirect to append/remove the trailing slash to canonicalise the URL instead.) You are also missing the `L` flag on the `RewriteRule`.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^league/([^/]+)/matches/?$ index.php?page_id=1074&league=$1 [L]
```

Although, if you are expecting digits only (as in your example) then you should be matching digits, not *anything*. So, the following is perhaps "more" correct:

```
RewriteRule ^league/(\d+)/matches/$ index.php?page_id=1074&league=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to write this reply.

This has actually gotten me much further than I've managed to on my own for the past two days of Googling and trying.

Now my problem seems to be a WordPress one. I can no longer access the $_GET['league'] query string variable that I previously was able to, although the redirect does appear to be working now other than this.

I'm not sure why I can't access the query string